# How do I make an username system for an local Multiplayer in C# and Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am programming a small mobile card game and have come to the point where the Players have to write their Names in an Input-Field.
So far ive got:

```
    public class namen : MonoBehaviour
{
    //InputField in Unity
    public InputField name;
    public Text player1;

    public void setget()        //Gets the players name back on the screen
    {
        player1.text = name.text;
    }

}
```

Now I have two main problems:

1. How can I make the number of players variable, so that I dont have to programm in a set
   number of maximum players?
2. How can I implement this in Unity?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use an **array** to set the name of the users - something like that:

```
public Text[x] player;
//x is an int with the maximum quantity of players
```

This way you can set a large number of players into this variable.
You can use a loop to insert the name of the players into the array.
Now about implementing, I didn't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am making a mobile-game where players play on one phone. The idea is that they get randomly generated challanges but the problem is I have no idea how I can have the names of the players show up on the start menue, so that you can check if all names are correct

Comment: Try creating something like a [combo box](https://youtu.be/URS9A4V_yLc) to show all  the names